# dpkg unpacking takes very long time on Ubuntu 20.04 & 20.10

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb

Ubuntu 20.10 is running (upgraded from 20.04) on AMD Platform PC. All run well except that the dpkg unpacking action took very long time, if not hours, to complete everytime some package was installed, such as the libreoffice or the linux kernel via `apt install` or others via `dpkg -i`. The problem existed since fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and lasted after upgrade to 20.10. What could be the possible reasons for this? How can I locate its origin step by step?

Some hardware information are attached below.

**`uname`**

```
Linux 5.8.0-31-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:44:54 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**`/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`**

```
[mq-deadline] none
```

**`df`**

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             814632     1804    812828   1% /run
/dev/sda4      205414308 58017176 136892940  30% /
tmpfs            4073152   157196   3915956   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               4096        0      4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1    200704    39108    161596  20% /boot/efi
tmpfs             814628     7524    807104   1% /run/user/1000
```

**`lscpu`**

```
Architecture:                    x86_64  
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit  
Byte Order:                      Little Endian  
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual  
CPU(s):                          4  
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3  
Thread(s) per core:              2  
Core(s) per socket:              2  
Socket(s):                       1  
NUMA node(s):                    1  
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD  
CPU family:                      21  
Model:                           101  
Model name:                      AMD PRO A12-8870 R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G  
Stepping:                        1  
Frequency boost:                 enabled  
CPU MHz:                         1742.286  
CPU max MHz:                     3700.0000  
CPU min MHz:                     1400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        7385.68
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
```

**`fdisk -l`**

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 97.74 MiB, 102486016 bytes, 200168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.32 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 97.86 MiB, 102612992 bytes, 200416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 255.57 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 217.89 MiB, 228478976 bytes, 446248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 140 KiB, 143360 bytes, 280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 55.36 MiB, 58052608 bytes, 113384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 64.35 MiB, 67477504 bytes, 131792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 119.24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: WDC PC SN520 SDAPMUW-128G-1001          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 38A4AE00-09AB-4977-9092-13DA414AE18F

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    411647    409600  200M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    411648    673791    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    673792 248194544 247520753  118G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 248195072 250066943   1871872  914M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM008-2FR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5B2E88B0-C62C-4FA8-90D2-53F92B6C3D9C

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3443525631 3443523584  1.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  3863037952 3904980991   41943040   20G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3  3904980992 3907028991    2048000 1000M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda4  3443525632 3863037951  419512320  200G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 64.77 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 31.07 MiB, 32579584 bytes, 63632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 31.06 MiB, 32571392 bytes, 63616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on a virtual machine installed on VirtualBox, try using IDE disk instead of SATA.

It solved the issue in my case.